# Bulk Api:Storage limit exceeded

Tags: bulk-api, curl, storage-limit

I am performing bulk api operations to load account records into salesforce using curl.I have a separate CSV file to do that job which consist of 5000 records.when I try uploading it, only 3500 records are being proceed and the remaining gets failed.

In result I am getting Error as:

> Storage limits exceeded

Any solutions?what should I do to upload all 5000 records?

Comment: Could you go to Administration Setup -> Data Management -> Storage Usage and see how much of free space are left for org? I am pretty sure that you are out of storage in salesforce, and there is nothing to do with bulk api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This has nothing to do with Bulk API. Since you have used all your orgs' DB storage, it stops you from creating any new objects
2. If you are in Free Developer Org it has very limited storage of 5 MB. Either delete unnecessary records (clear recycle bin) and free up some storage and retry. But sooner or later you will blow up this small memory.
3. If its production org then you need to buy additional storage. Please contact your salesforce.com account executive and choose between various pricing options which works for you

**Ref:** https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000ghqRAAQ